# How to send by email a d3 js chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to know if there is any way to embed or place a graphic made with d3 js in an email. Currently, I have a bar graph with d3 js and I would like to send it by mail. Is there a way to send by email this chart? Or take a screenshot of the graph and send it?

Regards.

Comment: You probably can't have js code on an email source. You could generated d3 charts statically and then send it the template static html/css/svg email. This example of d3 ssr could be helpful https://glitch.com/~server-side-d3js